# Python Exe make error "no module named google"

Tags: python, google-analytics, pyinstaller, exe

I have created an app with Spyder as IDE, my app works perfectly.

Then I create an exe in Pyinstaller.

Then I get an error "no module named google" when I launch the exe.

When i import google library i get "no module named google.analytics".

My app will import data from Google Analytics 4 and i use library: google.analytics.data_v1beta.

I tried to make app with Spyder env and I created separately env with library i used. On Pyinstaller i created hook file with one line `hiddenimports = ['google.analytics.data_v1beta', 'google', 'google.analytics']` but it doesn't work.

When i use `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import google data_from_analytycs_ga4.py` i got error similar  when i import google library in code: "no module named google.analytics"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.